# a.nodeName is undefined Jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodename

> a.nodeName is undefined

I've looked this up but the explanations didn't seem at all clear to me.

```
function deleteThisRow() {
    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(400, function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

```js
<tr>
    <td>blah blah blah</td>
    <td>
        <img src="/whatever" onClick="deleteThisRow()">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Inside `deleteThisRow`, `this` will refer to `window`, not the image. Why don't you bind the event handler with jQuery?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `this` keyword in your function does not refer to the element which was clicked on. By default it would refer to the highest element in the DOM, which would be the `window`.

To fix this you can use an unobtrusive event handler, instead of an outdated `on*` event attribute, as they run under the scope of the element which raised the event. Try this:

```js
$("tr td img").click(deleteThisRow);

function deleteThisRow() {
  $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(400, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>blah blah blah 1</td>
    <td><img src="/whatever"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>blah blah blah 2</td>
    <td><img src="/whatever"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>blah blah blah 3</td>
    <td><img src="/whatever"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Indeed, it appears this error means you used $(this) incorrectly. In this case, I was trying to call a function that I'd written assuming it would be called from a particular event, outside that event.

Comment: Hilariously, a couple years later, having forgotten this, I did exactly the same thing again, found this very helpful comment, went to upvote it, and couldn't, cause turns out I was the one who wrote it. Thanks, myself! :D

Comment: This was actually the answer to my problem, it just took ages for me to realise. Thank you! I'd moved some code into a function, but didn't change the $(this) references to input[name=etc] references.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").click(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(400, function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue and the solution was to switch from an arrow function to a traditional named function. Sometimes old is gold but I'm sure there is a root cause somewhere.

This didn't work:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#client_id').change(() => {
    const clientId = $(this).val();
    console.log(clientId);
  });
});
```

The console print out was the error:

> TypeError: i.nodeName is undefined

On further investigation it turned out '$(this)' was calling the window object rather than the select element. (As pointed out by Rory above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8817193/5925104)

This worked. A value was printed out to the console.

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#client_id').change(function changeClient() {
    const clientId = $(this).val();
    console.log(clientId);
  });
});
```

> UPDATE

This is one of the limitations of arrow functions. And I quote, "Does not have its own bindings to this or super, and should not be used as methods." Since the jQuery method above uses 'this' context, arrow functions should be avoided in such a case and a traditional function expression used instead. Here's the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to support this.